# NameError: name is not defined when using it in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a basic login that verifies if the password entered and the confirmation of that password match.

```
def login():  
  username = input("Please enter a username:")
  password = input("Please enter a password:")
  confirmPass = input("Please confirm your password:")

login()

if password == confirmPass:
  print("You have signed up")
```

I get the error that name password is not defined.

Comment: Read about local and global variables. This is not about the `if` about about the function.

Comment: Unless you mean to use local and global variables, its best not to. Declare your variables outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in the function `login` are limited to the **scope** of the function `login`.

You could move your check to within the function:

```
def login():  
  username = input("Please enter a username:")
  password = input("Please enter a password:")
  confirmPass = input("Please confirm your password:")
  if password == confirmPass:
    print("You have signed up")

login()
```

Other possibilities:

- Use global variables
- make the function `login` return a boolean and check the return value

Comment: I don't think use of globals should be encouraged, especially to a beginner.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I didn't mean to promote the use of global variables, I was just trying to point out that there's more than one way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, simply return the values from `password, confirm_pass` from your function. Also `snake_case` not `camelCase` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

```
def login():  
    username = input("Please enter a username:")
    password = input("Please enter a password:")
    confirm_pass = input("Please confirm your password:")
    return password, confirm_pass

password, confirm_pass = login()

if password == confirm_pass:
    print("You have signed up")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted and I added an extra peace(copy if you want):

```
name = input("enter a username: ")
password = input("enter a password")
repass = input("retype your passsword: ")

if password == repass:
 print("signed in.")
else:
 print("passwords do not match..")

#extra copy if you want...
name1 = input("enter a username: ")
password1 = input("enter a password: ")

if password1 == repass:
 if name1 == name:
  print ("logged in.")
 else:
   print("incorrect username")
else:
 print("incorrect password.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather return values out of a function - but if you would prefer to use module-level globals just define `username` and `password` before calling `login()`.

Something like:

```
def login():  
    username = input("Please enter a username:")
    password = input("Please enter a password:")
    confirmPass = input("Please confirm your password:")

username = ""
password = ""

login()

if password == confirmPass:
    print("You have signed up")
```

That should work the way you had expected, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It is best that you do not declare any variables within the function if you are not sure. Try the code below:

```
username = input("Please enter a username:")
password = input("Please enter a password:")
confirmPass = input("Please confirm your password:")

def match_password(password,confirmPass):  
    if password == confirmPass:
        print("You have signed up")
    else:
        print("Passwords do not match")

match_password(password,confirmPass)
```

All your variables are declared based on inputs outside your function to validate the passwords.